# what is the purpose of "as" here?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, relative-pronouns

> Use the Pythagorean Theorem to find the missing side, being  careful
>   to mark the value as positive or negative ***as*** makes sense in that
>   quadrant.

I simply cannot understand how, grammatically, "as" is used in that sentence. Is it used as a relative pronoun? I'm simply lost. Please help!

Comment: @Catija Thank you! It's not some mathematical term. It's just usual as.

Comment: It's the same as in "as you please" or "do X as you would do Y."  You could replace it with "in the manner in which" but it's rather less concise :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the documentation to support my answer, but if it helps I believe there is an implied pronoun:

Use the Pythagorean Theorem to find the missing side, being careful to mark the value as positive or negative **as** *it* makes sense in that quadrant.

It's similar to saying something like, "please stand as able" for a ceremony, implying "please stand as *you are* able," which contains not only an implied pronoun but an implied verb.

Comment: Thank you! But I don't understand why this "it" should have been elided. Does it sound unnatural with "it"? Is that why?

Comment: I agree the omission makes the sentence more awkward, but I've seen the omission in formal publications like textbooks as well as signage before.

Answer (score 1):

It's being used as a conjunction, and it seems most similar to this [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/as)

> Used to indicate by comparison the way that something happens or is done:
>   *they can do **as** they wish*
>   *she kissed him goodbye, **as** usual*

In your quote, it actually means something more like *whichever*.

Comment: So this second "as" (..."as" makes sense) is not related to the first "as" (value "as" positive or negative) at all, am I correct? Also, what is the noun that is implied or deleted? Is it "as _it_ makes sense?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The implied noun is the result of deciding between positive and negative, or the process of deciding.

Comment: I really appreciate it. But just one more question. Why is it elided? Does it sound better when elided?

Comment: Because restating it would be redundant. You already said to make the decision, this is just describing the reason for the decision.

Answer (score 1):

It is being used as a [conjunction](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/as_3) in this case to indicate the reason or time for doing something. In this case, it is a [subordinating](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/conjunctions.htm) conjunction with the clause:

> ...makes sense in that quadrant.

In other words, your values may have different signs depending on the quadrant.